# int.ToString() error on string concatenation Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cultureinfo

After i updated my Visual Studio 2019 from v16.2.5 to v16.3.5 some errors occured in my application in every place where i use string concatenation.

Ex:

```
int x = 5;
string y = x + " years";
```

What has changed? How does the Culture influences int?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have ticked the `treat warnings as errors` radio button.

An int can be displayed in western digits (0, 1, 2, 3, ... 9) or it can be displayed in other digits such as Arabic (٠  ١   ٢   ٣) or Thai (๑   ๒   ๓) and so on.

Therefor, an int representation is culture dependent, and hence the error.

For more information, check out [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1305?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but if I try to create a new project and do the same thing there are no errors or warnings about that, also I don't have the 'treat warnings as errors' checkbox checked

Comment: I believe that this is project related.

Comment: Did you add the the `System.Globalization` package to your new project?  check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#dependent-projects

Comment: I just looked over the code analysis option for my project and I found out that I have a custom rule that treats the warnings as errors. So the warning has been triggered by the code analysis.

Comment: I have my answer, thank you and @germi for your time.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 3):

This message stems from the code analysis feature of Visual Studio. For more info regarding this specific warning, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1305?view=vs-2019). There it says:

> [...] .NET members choose default culture and formatting based on
>   assumptions that might not be correct for your code. To make sure that
>   the code works as expected for your scenarios, you should supply
>   culture-specific information according to the following guidelines: [...]

It's generally good practice to be mindful of `.ToString` calls that end up being show to the user.